Closed Form for the coefficients of exponentiation in binary representation
I am trying to find a closed form for the coefficients for the following equation:
$$(\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}[2^i*a_i])^{p-2} \tag{1}$$
Note that, $a_i \in \{0,1\}$ and hence $a_i^n = a_i$, also $p \in \mathbb{P}$.
The formula is the exponentiation of binary representation of an integer.
Interestingly enough, one should always get $\leq 2^n -1$ terms, each of which has a coefficient. I am interested in a closed form for these coeffients, in other words, they denote the additive term when a subset of $a$ is all set to $1$.
As an example, let's take a 3 bit number ($n=3$) and $p=7$:
$$(\sum_{i=0}^{2}[2^i*a_i])^{5}$$
The result will be (without taking advantage of $a_i^n = a_i$):
$$a_0^5 + 10 a_1 a_0^4 + 20 a_2 a_0^4 + 40 a_1^2 a_0^3 + 160 a_2^2 a_0^3 + 160 a_1 a_2 a_0^3 + 80 a_1^3 a_0^2 + 640 a_2^3 a_0^2 + 960 a_1 a_2^2 a_0^2 + 480 a_1^2 a_2 a_0^2 + 80 a_1^4 a_0 + 1280 a_2^4 a_0 + 2560 a_1 a_2^3 a_0 + 1920 a_1^2 a_2^2 a_0 + 640 a_1^3 a_2 a_0 + 32 a_1^5 + 1024 a_2^5 + 2560 a_1 a_2^4 + 2560 a_1^2 a_2^3 + 1280 a_1^3 a_2^2 + 320 a_1^4 a_2$$
Now we can reduce this down to 7 terms by using $a_i^n = a_i$:
$$1a_0 + 32a_1 + 1024 a_2 + 210a_0a_1 + 2100a_0a_2 + 6720a_1a_2 + 6720a_0a_1a_2$$
These coefficients $(1,32,1024,210,2100,6720,6720)$ are what I would like to have a direct equation for, if it helps, I only need the coefficients mod $p$.
I have already been able to find out the following coefficients:
$$C(a_m) = (2^m)^{p-2}$$
$$C(a_m,a_n) = (2^n + 2^m)^{p-2} - (2^n)^{p-2} - (2^m)^{p-2}, \textrm{with } m < n$$
However, I haven't been able to generalize it to subsets larger than size 2.
I would love to have more formulas for the coefficients or a generalization and learn how to find such equations efficientely, in general any interesting observations regarding (1) as well as other ideas and attempts.
